# 10's complement confusion.

Tags: arithmetic, number-systems

For the sake of simplicity, lets consider only single digit numbers.
According to the logic(that I understand), 10's complement of a number 'x' is (10-x). So,

10's comp. of 0 = (10-0) = 10 (due to overflow, only 0 remains, so no -ve 0)(am I correct?),

10's comp. of 1 = (10-1) =  9 (representing -1),

10's comp. of 2 = (10-2) =  8 (representing -2),

10's comp. of 3 = (10-3) =  7 (representing -3),

10's comp. of 4 = (10-4) =  6 (representing -4),

10's comp. of 5 = (10-5) =  5 (representing -5) (here is the problem).

How can 5 represent -5?
If we cannot include +5, then 10's complemented 5 is the negative of whom?
how this problem is dealt with?
Am I making any mistake? Please explain in detail. Thank You!

Edit: How would a processor, which does 2's complement arithmetic(an extension of 10's complement) be able to distinguish between +5(5) and -5(5)?

Comment: $5+5=0$ so of course $5$ is its own negative.

Comment: Yes! so is 4+6, 3+7, 2+8, 1+9 and 0+10 but you can distinguish between say +4(4) and -4(6), how would you distinguish between +5(5) and -5(5)?

Comment: Since $+5$ and $-5$ turn out to be the same, you could just call it $5$. Compare to $0$: we have $+0 = -0$, but usually just write $0$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You really need more digits to see what is going on.  If you have a three digit register, we consider all numbers that start with $0$ to $4$ as positive and all numbers that start with $5$ to $9$ as negative.  The range of numbers you can represent is then $-500$ to $+499$.  Yes, $500$ and $-500$ would be represented by the same number, but any calculation that results in $+500$ should be considered an overflow.  In your example, $5$ would represent $-5$ and not $+5$.  $+5$ (and any higher positive number) cannot be represented in this system.

Comment: Thank you! I kind of understood, you mean, since we are using 5 as -5, 5 cannot be used in any calculation or result in a single digit system, we need at least a two digit system to get 5 whose 10's complement will be 95, am I right?  another thing, is there any advantage (mathematical/circuital) of using 5 as -5 and making 5 out of range instead of making both 5 and -5 out of range in single digit system?

Comment: Yes, to represent $5$ you need two digits.  In that case $-5$ is represented as $95$.  The nice thing about complement notation is that you can add, subtract, and multiply without worrying about signs, so $-2 + (-2)$ is represented as $8+8=6$ (with a carry you ignore) and the result is $-4$.  In four bit two's complement the negative numbers range from $1000$, which represents $-8$, to $1111$, which represents $-1$ and the positives range from $0001$, which represents $1$ up to $0111$, which represents $7$.  This shows why we keep the most negative value-it lets the high order bit be the sign.

Comment: Keeping one of $5,-5$ just gives you more range than excluding them both.

Answer (score 0):

What you seem to be looking for is perhaps [additive inverse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Additive_inverse) for a group where the [additive identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Additive_identity) is given by $I=10$.

Answer (score 0):

If you understand modular arithmetic, you will know that it's just a definition. For example under mod 10, 1 is equivalent to -9.

Imagine a clock with numbers 0 to 9, moving 5 units forward is the same as moving five units backward 0 9 8 7 6 5 or 0 1 2 3 4 5